# Cloning public repository on GitHub using SourceTree

Tags: c++, git, github, clone, git-clone

I want to clone [SFML](https://github.com/SFML/SFML) ([this git](https://github.com/SFML/SFML.git)) with SourceTree and it seems to be stuck?

This is the SourceTree output:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false clone --recursive https://github.com/SFML/SFML.git C:\Users\admin\Documents\SFML
Cloning into 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\SFML\'...
```

I see the loading bar but nothing happens. No errors, nothing. It just keeps loading and nothing happens (but I see network activity).

Can someone please tell me what to do? It's my first time cloning with SourceTree and I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

(I don't have a GitHub account by the way, but the repo is public, so I don't know if that's the issue here?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work just fine, except it does take quite a while to complete.

I tried it in command line:

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git>git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false clone --recursive https://github.com/SFML/SFML.git
Cloning into 'SFML'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 21761, done.
remote: Counting objects: 12, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Receiving objects:  39% (8643/21773), 33.50 MiB | 636.00 KiB/s
```

... a few minutes later:

```
remote: Total 21773 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (21773/21773), 54.53 MiB | 629.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (15085/15085), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Checking out files: 100% (726/726), done.
```

Comment: Oh, wow. Turns out it just took a really long time... almost 20 minutes for me. They should really add some kind of percentage indicator to SourceTree. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @A.D. If that answer provided with some help, maybe could you consider accepting it?